# Cryptic Family Reunion #9

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are sorted with answers in alphabetical order, and lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Daughter's clean wound healed (10)
2. After California and Nevada, like, return to Mom (10)
3. Brother's girlfriend caught heading due west with a forlorn heart (7)
4. Grandma drinking every bit of liquor up (7)
5. Auntie freaks out near germs (9)
6. Uncle belts beer after beer (7)
7. Nephew green after leader pars hole (7)
8. Sister's sheer heartless embrace devastated love (8)
9. Son set the table at every other place (4)
10. "We doing goulash?", suggested Dad (7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theme is:

> **species of ducks**

Explanation:

> 1. buff + healed* -- BUFFLEHEAD
>  2. CA + NV + as + back -- CANVASBACK
>  3. ga(d_ w_ + a + forLorn)l -- GADWALL
>  4. dram< containing all -- MALLARD
>  5. neargerms* -- MERGANSER
>  6. pint + "ale" (homophone)  -- PINTAIL
>  7. p(ars) + O + chard -- POCHARD
>  8. sh(e)er containing love* -- SHOVELER
>  9. 'thetable' every other letter -- TEAL
>  10. wedoing* -- WIDGEON

Comment: Crushed it @LannyStrack!